# Write char[128] array to file in C

Tags: c, string, file

I wrote a program to test writing a char[128] array to file using write() function in C. The following is my code, however, after writing, I can see that the string "testseg" is followed by a "d" or "È" in the testFile.txt file. Is this a proper way of writing char[] array to file?

```
int main()
{
    char pathFile[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN];
    sprintf(pathFile, "testFile.txt");
    int filedescriptor = open(pathFile, O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0777);

    int num_segs = 10;
    int mods = 200;
    const char *segname = "testseg";  /* */
    char real_segname[128];
    strcpy(real_segname, segname);

    write(filedescriptor, &num_segs, sizeof(int));
    write(filedescriptor, real_segname, strlen(real_segname));
    printf("real_segname length is %d \n", (int) strlen(real_segname));
    write(filedescriptor, &mods, sizeof(int));

    close(filedescriptor);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After wwriting srting, your writing 200(mod) into file. that 200 is "d" or "È"

Comment: Succinctly, yes; it is one proper way to do it.  However, you may have some problems reading the data back; you won't know how long the string is.  This is often fixed by using a fixed-length write (for example, using `strncpy(real_segname, segname, sizeof(real_segname);` and then `write(filedescriptor, real_segname, sizeof(real_segname));` — or by including a length before the string: `short s = strlen(segname); write(filedescriptor, &s, sizeof(s)); write(filedescriptor, real_segname, s);`.

Comment: Is the "d" or "E" the very next byte after `testseg`? Because you're writing `mods` after that. Could that be it?

Comment: As @SGG said, you are writing that data. The `write` function writes binary data. If you want the numbers to be human readable you should print them to a string using sprintf and then write that string. You may also want to add a new line character `'\n'`

Answer (score 2):

...writing a char[128] array to file ...I can see that the string "testseg" ...
is a contradiction.

In C, a string is an array of `char` followed by and including a `'\0'` and 
a `char[128]` is a fixed 128 `char` in length.

When code does `write(filedescriptor, real_segname, strlen(real_segname));`, it does neither.  It is not writing a C string, 7 `char` of "testseg" terminated with a `'\0'`.  Instead it just wrote the 7 `char` and no terminating `'\0'`.  Neither did it write 128 `char`.

One *could* instead perform `write(filedescriptor, real_segname, strlen(real_segname)+1);` to write the 7 `char` and the terminating `'\0'`.  Or write the length and then the interesting parts of the arry.  Or write the entire 128 `char` array`.  Need to identify how you want to read data back and other coding goals to well advise.

As @SGG suggests, the unusually `char` are simply the result of `write(filedescriptor, &mods, sizeof(int));` and are not part of your unterminated array.

Comment: yes, you're right. It won't write NULL character. I didn't cared that :(.

Answer (score 1):

`after writing, I can see that the string "testseg" is followed by a "d" or "È" in the testFile.txt file`

**Why it is showing "d" or "È"??**

Only try below  `write` function (in your code, comment remaining write calls except below call)

```
write(filedescriptor, &mods, sizeof(int));
```

Now see the contents of `testFile.txt` (`cat testFile.txt`). It shows some junk value(s).

Because, all `.txt` files will show you in the form of `ASCII text` format. It converts every byte into `ASCII` charcter. String and characters you're writing in ASCII format and reading them as ASCII. So no problem. But here you're writing `mods and num_segs` as integers and reading them as ASCII format. So you got those junk values.

`Is this a proper way of writing char[] array to file?`

Yes, according to man pages you're writing them in proper way. And please make sure to validate your function calls(`write`). Where to write, what to write in a file depends upon your requirement.